# Why state is not storing data correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am getting data through axios and storing that in a state

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCartItems();
}, []);

const [abc, setAbc] = useState([]);

const getCartItems = async () => {
  let data = await CartApi.get(`/${store.getState().auth.user.id}/`)
    .then(({ data }) => data);
  console.log('data =>', data)
  data.map(a => setAbc([...abc, a.item]))
}
```

I print the data variable in the console, and it gives the following output

[image: data]

But after that I store `data.item` in another state, but it is not storing first one. If I run `console.log(abc)` it shows only 24

[image: abc]

Why i'm not getting [32,24]

Comment: You'd need to use the function form of setAbc to make sure you're modifying the latest state of abc.

Comment: calling use state dunction inside a loop is not a good idea it will render your screen too many times. also where you are consoling abc? add that code

Comment: create local variable and asssign all values to that variable imside loop and after completing loop set that value to useState

Comment: Side note: The code shown misuses `map`. If you're not using the array that `map` builds and returns, it's not the right tool for what you're doing. More in my blog post here: [*Misusing `map`*](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're reusing the same `abc` in every one of those calls to `setAbc`, so only the *last* of the items is actually added. Remember that the state setter doesn't change the `abc` constant you're using, it schedules a new call to your component function that will get the new value for `abc` from `useState`.

When updating data based on existing data, you should use the callback form. Also, there's no reason to make repeated `setAbc` calls, just make one with all the new data, see `***` comments:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCartItems();
},[]);
const[abc,setAbc]=useState([]);
const getCartItems = async () => {
    let data = await CartApi.get(`/${store.getState().auth.user.id}/`).then(({data})=>data);
    const items = data.map(({item}) => item);  // *** Get the items
    setAbc(abc => [...abc, ...items]);         // *** Save them
//         ^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− *** Use the callback form
}
```

(The primary fix there is to do `[...abc, ...items]` **once**. Although I do recommend using the callback, in many cases, just `setAbc([...abc, ...items]);` would work as well provided you don't memoize `getCartItems` and this is only done on mount or in response to a user click or similar.)